# Representing multivariable functions as vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I’m going through some Linear Algebra material and started to wonder that if we can represent functions as vectors for example the elements of $C([0,1])$. These are all usually presented with the case where $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ so that all the vectors $\textbf{f} = f(x_1)e_1 + \cdots + f(x_n)e_n$. So what if I have functions of the form $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$? Initially I started to think that this would force $\textbf{f}$ to be a matrix instead of a vector?

Comment: Of course if $f$ is a function from $\mathbb R^n \to R^m$ it is a vector $$\underline {f}(x_1,\dots, x_n)=\begin{pmatrix}f_1(x_1,\dots,x_n)\\\vdots\\f_m(x_1,\dots, x_n) \end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

Of course if $f$ is a function from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^m$, it is a vector $$\underline {f}(x_1,\dots, x_n)=\begin{pmatrix}f_1(x_1,\dots,x_n)\\\vdots\\f_m(x_1,\dots, x_n) \end{pmatrix},$$ where the functions $f_1\,\dots,f_m$ are function from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R$.
An example could be the function $\underline f:\mathbb R^3\to \mathbb R^2$ such that
$$\underline f(x,y,z)=\begin{pmatrix}e^{x+y}-y+\sin z\\x^2-e^y+3\cos z \end{pmatrix}$$
but I didn't understand what you wrote about the representation of such a function by a matrix.

If a function is $\underline f:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^m$, the image of $\underline f$ is a vector in $\mathbb R^m$, whose components are the functions $f_1(x_1,\dots,x_n),f_2(x_1,\dots,x_n),\dots,f_m(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ and its "derivative" corresponds to
$$\operatorname{M}(m\times n,\mathbb R)\ni J_{\underline f}(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\begin{pmatrix}\nabla f_1(x_1,\dots,x_n)\\\nabla f_2(x_1,\dots,x_n)\\\vdots\\\nabla f_m(x_1,\dots,x_n)\end{pmatrix}.$$